# complex issue with mysql "NOTIN"

Tags: mysql

select query is like this want to fetch party records which are not in tranjectionbackup
with this query i get all record in result i am try with left outer join still give me same result. 
where is my mistake i do not know exactly what should i do to get perfect result anyone help me out with my query.

```
SELECT * FROM party 
    WHERE partyId NOT IN (SELECT partyId FROM tranjectionbackup)
```

Comment: could you create a fiddle with some sample data and what is the datatype of `partyId`

Comment: There's not enough information provided to answer your question. Beware of NULL values being returned by the subquery, that would result in *no* rows being returned. And beware of NULL values in the `partyId` column of `party` as well. A query using an anti-join pattern would return an equivalent result. A SQL Fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would provide your (simplified) table definitions and  example data that demonstrates the behavior you are observing. (I don't think it's "complex issue" at all.)

Comment: which kind of data u want to see @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Example tables, and exemplar data, preferably in a SQL Fiddle [http://sqlfiddle.com/], that demonstrates the behavior you are observing. As the question stands now, it's not answerable.

Comment: Your title should be a one-sentence _summary_ of your issue, not a _description_ of it.

Comment: I was going to edit this question but I don't even know what you're trying to say. "i get all record in result i am try with left outer join still give me same result".  Are you saying you are getting all rows from 'party' even if they have rows in 'tranjectionbackup'?